# Trouble writing to html file with python

Tags: python, html

I'm having trouble writing a very simple html file in python.

The code is:

```
filehtml = 'C:\pathhere\helloworld.html'

message = '''<html>
<head></head>
<body><p><Hello World!</p></body>
</html>'''

f = open(filehtml,'w')
f.write(message)
f.close()
```

The file appears, is about 65 bytes, but when I open it in chrome or firefox it's blank. There's a little lock on the file icon, but when I right click on options, the permissions include me.  So...I don't know if this is a code problem or something else.  Also, all the other files on my desktop have locks and I open them just fine. 
I looked here for help ([How to write and save html file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523939/how-to-write-and-save-html-file-in-python))

I'm using Windows 7, python 2.7 Anaconda
Thanks.

Comment: Open the file in notepad to see if it is writing properly

Comment: Btw, you should use the `with`-syntax

Comment: Flagged to close because this is a find my typo question

Comment: I see now, sorry! I read over it waaaayy to many times, all before coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `<` which is messing everything up.

```
filehtml = 'C:\pathhere\helloworld.html'

message = '''<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>Hello World!</p></body>
</html>'''

f = open(filehtml,'w')
f.write(message)
f.close()
```