# How to insert text and images in a row in html file using python?

Tags: python, html

I want to save text and two images side-by-side in html file using python. How I can do it?
Example of what I want is below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBQjX.png

Comment: Do you mean that css is not matter? And which framework do you use? django?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523939/how-to-write-and-save-html-file-in-python