# Output isn't shown per line

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I wrote a simple python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import urllib

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'usage: python %s <file-urls>' % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(2)

print '%-15s %15s' % ('URL_PAGE', 'STATUS')

FileName = sys.argv[1]
InputFile = open(FileName)
for url in InputFile:
    out = urllib.urlopen(url)
    status = out.getcode()
    print '%-15s %15s' % (url, status)
```

The out put is something like this:

```
URL_PAGE                 STATUS
http://test.com
             200
```

But I want this output:

```
URL_PAGE                 STATUS
http://test.com           200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip` the newline character (and useless whitespace) from `url`:

```
print '%-15s %15s' % (url.strip(), status)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you...may I have another question? How can I write the out put to file in this thread?

Comment: @MortezaLSC, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file