# String Output in a data file

Tags: python, string, output

How to print string in data file ? I have checked this [Python Print String To Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file). But this is not really helping me. 
The part of the code is like this :

```
for k in range(len(energy)):
        str = "%12.4e %12.4e " %(energy[k], spectra[0][k])
        for j in range(1,spectra.shape[0]):
            str += "%12.4 " % spectra[j][k]
        print str
```

Now i want this string output in a data file. How this can be done ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't name a variable `str`. That's the name of a builtin function.

To answer your question: Open a file and `write` to it.

```
with open("/tmp/out.txt", "w") as o:    
    for k in range(len(energy)):
        s = "%12.4e %12.4e " %(energy[k], spectra[0][k])
        for j in range(1,spectra.shape[0]):
            s += "%12.4 " % spectra[j][k]
        o.write(s)
```

Note that this does not add newlines! If you need them, add a `\n` at the end of `s`.