# Converting pandas dataframe into basket type orange table

Tags: python, pandas, orange

I have the following pandas dataframe and would like any pointers in converting this to an Orange table with a basket format:

```
orders_item=pandas.DataFrame({'order_number':['001','002','002','002','003','003','003','003','003'],
'item':['Beef','Beef','Fish','Eggs','Beef','Oil','Salt','Pepper','MSG']})
```

I'll like to convert it to an orange table with Basket format similar to this:

```
Beef

Beef, Fish, Eggs

Beef, Oil, Salt, Pepper, MSG
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd groupby the order_id and print the results:

```
In [11]: for row in orders_item.groupby("order_number")["item"]:
             print(",".join(row[1]))
Beef
Beef,Fish,Eggs
Beef,Oil,Salt,Pepper,MSG
```

If you want the string:

```
In [12]: "\n\n".join([", ".join(row[1]) for row in orders_item.groupby("order_number")["item"]])
Out[12]: 'Beef\n\nBeef, Fish, Eggs\n\nBeef, Oil, Salt, Pepper, MSG'
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I store that into an orange table?

Comment: You save it as a `*.basket` file and load it with Orange?

Comment: @BlackHat See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5214578/1240268) to save a string to a file in python. Note that the other option is to export to csv (with `.to_csv`) and then read the csv with orange table.

Comment: Finally get it. I completely ignored the .basket extension. This makes sense.