# How do you save the inputs into text file?

Tags: python, file, text, text-files, saving-data

How do i save the inputs of program into a file from the program.
Python only:
i need to add it to this:

## TASK 2 AGAIN

```
sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
print(sentence)
word=input("Please enter word and position wil be shown: ")
if word in sentence:
    print("Found word")
else:
    print ("Word not found")
```

But i haven't got a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to have two main parts to it: how do I get inputs in Python and how do I save data to a file in Python.

To get input from the terminal:

```
>>> data = input('Input: ')
>>> Input: hello, world!
```

To save to a file:

```
>>> with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
>>>    f.write(data)
```

You can find more information about inputs [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html) and file i/o [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Edit 0: @Gazzer, if you want to save `sentence + input` you'll need to do `f.write(sentence + input)` rather than using `.save()`.

Edit 1: @Gazzer, I got something like the below to work (*note: the code does not show position of the found word*):

```
sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
word = input("Please enter word and position wil be shown: ")
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{} {}'.format(sentence, word))
```

If you run into more issues, there are hundreds of resources all over the web to ask for help.  Stack Overflow, [learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming), and many more.

Next time you ask a question, it is really helpful for those answering if you provide a code snippet you are working on and what the problem/errors are.

Comment: I did try that.. I got an error message saying that write wasn't not defined

Comment: But thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is what you're asking for

```
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")

text_file.write(stuff)

text_file.close()
```

Comment: Yes that is what i was looking for thank you!

Comment: sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
print(sentence)
word=input("Please enter word and position wil be shown: ")
if word in sentence:
    print("Found word")
else:
    print ("Word not found")
text_file = open("Output.txt","w")
text_file.save(sentence + input)
text_file.close()
It doesn't work in this code

Comment: 1) The code you just commented doesn't include "text_file.write" try that... 2) You've posted a question that has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file and you are just asking for answers not for help