# How to write form data to a text document

Tags: python, wtforms

I'm trying to get my form data to be captured and written to a word document. I have the following function...

```
def index():
    FILE_TYPES = set(['txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'text', 'wks', 'wps', 'wpd'])
    mail = Mail(app)
    errors = '' 
    form = ApplicationForm(CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form)))
    capture = [form.department.data, form.name.data, form.address.data, str(form.telephone.data), form.email.data, form.explain.data]
    department_data = form.department.data
    name_data = form.name.data
    if department_data == 'cpoms':
        flash(capture)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Thanks %s, we will try to get back to your regarding you application as soon as possible.' % form.name.data) 
        print "Form successfully submitted"
        submit_name = form.file_upload.data.filename
        if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
            filename = secure_filename(submit_name)
            form.file_upload.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
            return redirect('home')
```

Does anyone know how I can move the data from the capture variable and write this to a text document?

Comment: This question actually doesn't really affect Flask. Instead it's about writing text into a file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file for this.

Comment: Removed flask from tags. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
with open("/path/to/file.txt", "a") as write_file:
    for cap in capture:
        write_file.write(capt)
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: It ran as expected although didn't seem to write anything to the text file. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Was the file created at least?

Comment: Sorry, It did work was looking in the wrong file! Thanks.