# Drawing a pyramid to save in file

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to save a string with multiple prints in for function? I am able to draw a pyramid, but I am stuck on writing it to a file.

Here is my code:

```py
n = int(input("Enter number: "))
file_1 = open("pyramid.txt", "a")

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n - i + 1):
        file_1.write(" ", end="")
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        file_1.write("* ", end="")
    print("")

file_1.close()
```

Comment: I assume the `end=""` is giving you problems ... ?

Comment: check this so question [python-print-string-to-text-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file)

Comment: @JefréN. do you know what can i replace end with?

Comment: Just wait a sec ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *a little bit* broken. You are printing to create a newline, but write the rest to the file.

To output the pyramid to stdout (the terminal output):

```py
n = int(input("Enter number: "))
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n - i + 1):
        print(" ", end="")
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print("* ", end="")
    print("")
```

To output it to the file:

```
n = int(input("Enter number: "))
file_1 = open("pyramid.txt", "a")

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n - i + 1):
        file_1.write(" ")
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        file_1.write("* ")
    file_1.write("\n")

file_1.close()
```

Shortened:

```
n = int(input("Enter number: "))
print("\n".join(" " * (n - i) + "* " * i for i in range(1, n + 1)))
```

or

```
n = int(input("Enter number: "))
f = open("pyramid.txt", "w")
f.write("\n".join(" " * (n - i) + "* " * i for i in range(1, n + 1)) + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Good answer, especially with the added detail. +!

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Seems easy to do as well. Thanks for the help man :)