# PYTHON how to write a str input text to a text file

Tags: python, string, text, input

I have a problem every time i try and save the text i write for "ime" or "autor" to an external text file. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem so i can store the info in an organized "category" like manner would be greatly appreciated.

```
def unosenje_knjiga():
    file = open("2.rtd", "a")
    ime = str(input("Ime knjige:"))
    while len(ime) <= 3:
        print("Molimo Vas unesite ime knjige ponovo!")
        ime = str(input("Ime knjige:"))

    autor = str(input("Autor knjige:"))
    while len(autor) <= 0:
        print("Molimo Vas unesite ime autora ponovo!")
        ime = str(input("Autor knjige:"))

    isbn = str(input("ISBN knjige:"))
    while len(isbn) <= 0:
        print("Molimo Vas unesite ISBN knjige ponovo!")
        ime = str(input("ISBN knjige:"))
```

Comment: Well you never seem to write to the file anyway. What is the format you want to use?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can write a string `s` to an opened file by `file.write(s)`

One simple format to store your data would be [Comma Separated Values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

So all you need to do it join the three strings together and write them to the file:

```
s = '"%s","%s","%s"' % (ime,autor,isbn)
file.write(s + "\n")
```

You might want to fix your two while loops. Your second query always sets variable ime instead of autor/isbn.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can not use `ime = str(input("Ime knjige:"));`

instead use 
`ime = raw_input("Ime knjige:");` because if you use `ime = input("...")` python  tries to interpret the '...' as a valid python expression

as example, type in a shell

```
     str = input("enter input")
```

as input type `5+4`, then

```
      print str
```

the result will be 9 because if you use input the content of the input is evaluated

2. if you want to write something to a file you have to open a handle to the file then write/read to/from it and when finished close the file handle (search for 'python file input output')

   `#!/usr/bin/python`

   `# Open a file`

   `fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")` //binary file io

   `fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");`

   `# Close opened file`

   `fo.close()`

see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm