# In python, how to write result which is showed on terminal as a .txt file?

Tags: python

I have been learning python for a week. but I'm not sure how I can save the result as a file.

```
def process_rows(self, rows):
    for row in rows:
        self.rownum+=1
        print(rownum)
```

I think there will be over 400000 results.
But Termial shows only 8000 results from 441810 to 450000.

I wanna save the result on a .txt file and read.
I have changed my code as follows.

```
def process_rows(self, rows):
    f = open("output_file", 'a+')
    for now in rows:
        self.rownum +=1
        f.write(rownum + "\n")
    f.close()
```

But exception error has occurred.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception in /conn 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 415, in _run_callback
  callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "server.py", line 98, in process_rows
  f.write(rownum + "\n")
NameError: global name 'rownum' is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Print String To Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file)

Comment: Please, take a look at documentation, here is everything you need: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Please _read_ the error message before posting here.

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def process_rows(self, rows):
    f = open("output_file", 'a+')
    for now in rows:
        self.rownum +=1
        f.write(str(self.rownum) + "\n")
    f.close()
```

You had two errors in one line: 1) omitting 'self.'; 2) adding int + string, as message said.

If you read doc for `print` and `write`, as suggested, you would discover that `print` automatically converts objects to string, using the default formatting, which `write` does not.  When writing to a file, one often wants to specify the exact formatting.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to go:

1. redirect print output to a file.

Note that print takes an integer `rownum` and displays `str()` of it.

```
def process_rows(self, rows):
    f = open("output_file", 'a+')
    for row in rows:
        self.rownum+=1
        print(rownum, file = f)
```

2. use correct data types for addition operation.

What you are doing in your second snippet is adding an integer `rownum` to a string `'\n'`, which is not a valid operation. You need to convert integer to a corresponding string first:

```
def process_rows(self, rows):
    f = open("output_file", 'a+')
    for now in rows:
        self.rownum +=1
        f.write(str(rownum) + "\n")
    f.close()
```