# not able to insert data into an empty file created using touch in Python code

Tags: python, linux

```
  commands.getoutput("touch /mytxt.txt")
  x="hello"
  commands.getoutput("echo x | cat >> /mytxt.txt".format(x))
```

I tried to run this code in python live interpreter , it runs perfectly ,data is inserted into the file. but when i put this code in python program it shows no such file and directory. but file mytxt gets created into the / folder

Comment: Try it without /. As it requires special permissions.

Comment: Two solutions  1. Remove /   2. run script using superuser permissions (sudo). 1st is recommended.

Comment: Kindly show ur Python code.. u must use Python module `import os` for
 executing linux commands via Python like `os.system('ls')` .

Comment: @Abhishakegupta she is using commands module  https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html , which does the same but depreacated.

Comment: There has been no activity for some time. Can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

> [Python Print String To Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file)

If you write python code and not a shell script, I guess you want to use python built-in functions to manage your files.

Answer (score 0):

I just has a similar issue on a server with php code. I edited the files as root, but then the web server could not write to the file.

The issue is that Apache (or your web server) does not have read/write access. like as a Group owner to the file/folder

Setting the GROUP permission, and set the folder so the web server has full read/write access too.