# How do I stdout all my outputs into one txt file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project here a work and I have print lines being displayed for 5+ elements. I need to add all the outputs into a txt file. I was told I can use a for loop but not sure how. What are my best options.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('website')
driver.maximize_window()

# Displays Time Sheet for Current Day
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[1]/h1')  
# this element is visible

print(element.text)

# Displays Start Time
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="pageinner"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')
print("Start time was at:", element.text)

# Displays End Time
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="pageinner"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]')
print("Clocked out as of:", element.text)

# Displays when out to Lunch
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-
inner"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h3')
print("I left for Lunch at:", element.text)

# Displays when back from Lunch
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-
inner"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/h3')
print("I arrived back from Lunch at:", element.text)

# Total Hours for The Day
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-
inner"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]')
print("I was at work for:", element.text)

'''
# Save to txt
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
print(element.text)
'''

# Screenshot
# driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')


driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

At the end Here I need to save all the prints into a txt file for documentation.

Comment: Do you mean 'move `stdout` into a `.txt` file'? You can just `python myfile.py > out.txt`.

Comment: Otherwise, visit https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html and Ctrl+F for `file`.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesnt work

Comment: It just says invalid syntax

Comment: You are likely using Python 3 then, where print is a function with a file keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Print String To Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file)

Comment: I am using PyCharm to write and run the code.

Comment: This kind of sucks - I wish I could do something about that.

Answer (score 1):

**`Selenium 3.5`** with **`Python 3.6.1`** bindings provides a simpler way to redirect all the **`Console Outputs`** into a log file.

You can create a sub-directory within your Project space by the name `Log` and start redirecting the **`Console Outputs`** into a log file as follows:

```
# Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\your_path\geckodriver.exe', log_path='./Log/geckodriver.log')

# Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\your_path\chromedriver.exe', service_log_path='./Log/chromedriver.log')

# IE
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\your_path\IEDriverServer.exe', log_file='./Log/IEdriver.log')
```

> It is worth to mention that the verbosity of the **`webdriver`** is easily configurable.