# concisely writing entire string to file python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more concise way of doing the following, e.g. on a single line and without the temporary variable `f`?

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foobar')
```

I'm often writing a bunch of files in scripts and this looks ugly, e.g. in one of my test scripts I have the following ugly:

```
sorted_alembic_schema = sort_lines_without_commas(alembic_schema)
sorted_sqlalchemy_schema = sort_lines_without_commas(sqlalchemy_schema)
if sorted_alembic_schema != sorted_sqlalchemy_schema:
    for file_name, file_contents in [('alembic.schema', alembic_schema),
                                     ('sqlalchemy.schema', sqlalchemy_schema),
                                     ('alembic.schema.sorted', sorted_alembic_schema),
                                     ('sqlalchemy.schema.sorted', sorted_sqlalchemy_schema)]:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            f.write(file_contents)
    print("""
ERROR: alembic upgrade schema doesn't match sqlalchemy schema; see local files for more info, e.g.

meld sqlalchemy.schema alembic.schema
meld sqlalchemy.schema.sorted alembic.schema.sorted

FAIL"""
          )
```

Comment: No, there is no other more concise way then what you are already doing with `with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('foobar')` and I do not think this is ugly at all. The rest of your code may be harder to read but that is a matter of preference. Personally I think your code is more difficult to read because: 1) you define that four-line list in the loop; and 2) you use *many* excessively long variable and function names.

Comment: @AGNGazer lol, you are right that my ugly code has little to do with the two line file writing, maybe I was looking for a scape goat

Comment: @wp78de This question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file ; please don't close.  This differs because it is explicitly asking if there is a more concise way to write this while the other question essentially asks the idiomatic way to write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` keyword is already a compression which opens, flushes, and closes something. There’s no one word compression of that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly code cannot be avoided all the time, and ugly code is not necessarily bad code. However, there is certainly room for improvement.

Regarding file writing: Extract a method for it

```
def StringToFile(file_path, content):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(content)
```

or use an external library function like [numpy.savetext](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
np.savetxt('test.out', x, delimiter=',')   # X is an array
```

Answer (score 0):

The temporary variable f represents the open file object. The with block takes care of opening the file and locking it for writing (os-level). The write-lock is released when the with block closes. I think the way you have it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that handles the writing in a single line, but it would just be an encapsulation of what you have already written.

```
def quick_write(file_path, content):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(content)
```

In your code, it would replace the 2 line with-statement:

```
if sorted_alembic_schema != sorted_sqlalchemy_schema:
    for file_name, file_contents in [...]:
        quick_write(file_name, file_contents)
```