# Python writing a .txt file

Tags: python, file, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
print('Welcome, I am Sam. I am ABMs personal assistant, today we will be pooling tips together!')

file = open(“tipsdate.txt”,”w”) 

name=str(input('Who do I have the pleasure of working with? '))

tips=int(input('How many tips did we collect today? '))
workers=int(input('How many people worked today? '))
cars=int(input('How many cars did we park today?'))

if workers == 1:
        print('Worker 1 earned $',tips)
elif workers == 2:
        a=int(input('How many hours did worker 1 work? '))
        b=int(input('How many hours did worker 2 work? '))
        totalhrs=a+b
        tipsa= (a/totalhrs)* tips
        tipsb= (b/totalhrs)*tips
        print('Worker one earned $',tipsa)
        print('Worker two earned $',tipsb)
elif workers == 3:
        a=int(input('How many hours did worker 1 work? '))
        b=int(input('How many hours did worker 2 work? '))
        c=int(input('How many hours did worker 3 work? '))
        totalhrs=a+b+c
        tipsa= (a/totalhrs)* tips
        tipsb= (b/totalhrs)*tips
        tipsc= (c/totalhrs)*tips
        print('Worker one earned $',tipsa)
        print('Worker two earned $',tipsb)
        print('Worker three earned $',tipsc)
elif workers == 4: 
        a=int(input('How many hours did worker 1 work? '))
        b=int(input('How many hours did worker 2 work? '))
        c=int(input('How many hours did worker 3 work? '))
        d=int(input('How many hours did worker 4 work? '))
        totalhrs=a+b+c+d
        tipsa= (a/totalhrs)* tips
        tipsb= (b/totalhrs)*tips
        tipsc= (c/totalhrs)*tips
        tipsd= (d/totalhrs)*tips
        print('Worker one earned $',tipsa)
        print('Worker two earned $',tipsb)
        print('Worker three earned $',tipsc)
        print('Worker four earned $', tipsd)
elif workers > 4:
    print('I am not programmed to calculate tips beyond 4 workers, I am a work in progress!')

cartips=tips/cars
print('Our tips per car average today was $ ',cartips)
file.close() 


print('Thank you for your help',name,'I hope we work together again soon! :) ')
```

Hi there, thanks for taking your time to help me. I am an amateur, self taught python coder. I am trying to figure out how to write a .txt file with conditional loops and various user inputs. I realize that this is noobie, but how does one allow for all this information to be stored in a .txt file?

This is for my valet parking job, just a fun side project to help me get more experience! Thank you. Any suggestions are welcome too, to improve my code - I realize its probably screams noob!

Comment: You need to use `file.write` everywhere you need to write to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Print String To Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file)

Comment: [Here's a link that should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214587/3180386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.write` instead of `print` would write if to a file. Also `input` writes to the monitor and not the file. Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

You need not repeat the code for each of the workers, instead you can do something like this which *loops* over the *variable* sized `workers`:

```
tips = 100
workers = [("w1", 8), ("w2", 8)]
hours = 0
with open("scratch.log", "w") as f:
    for worker, hour in workers:
        hours = hours + hour
    print(hours)
    f.write("%s\n" % str(hours))
    for worker, hour in workers:
        tip = (float(tips) / float(hours)) * hour
        print(worker, tip)
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (worker, str(tip)))
```

Overall code is:

```
newline = '\n'

name = str(input('Name? '))
tips = int(input('Total Tips? '))
workers = int(input('Total Workers Today? '))
cars = int(input('Cars Parked Today? '))

worker_hours = []
total_hours = 0

for idx, worker in enumerate(range(workers)):
    count = idx + 1
    hours = int(input('How many hours did worker %s work? ' % count))
    worker_hours.append(('w' + str(count), hours))

with open("tips.log", "w") as f:
    for worker, hours in worker_hours:
        total_hours = total_hours + hours
    print(total_hours)
    f.write("%s" % str(total_hours))
    f.write(newline)
    for worker, hours in worker_hours:
        tip = (float(tips) / float(total_hours)) * hours
        print(worker, tip)
        f.write("%s %s" % (worker, str(tip)))
        f.write(newline)  
    cartips = tips/cars
    print('Tips per car today was $%s.' % cartips)
    f.write('Tips per car today was $%s.' % cartips)
    f.write(newline)
```

Comment: @KyleOliver, did this help in solving your problem?

Comment: So basically there is not an efficient way of writing the data to a file?

Comment: The inputs dont need to be on the file, just the printed information. IS there a way to print and write to the file, sir? Thank you, as I said im a noob :)

Comment: @KyleOliver, I have updated that! That is so trivial. You can write a simple function that does both and call that.

Comment: Thank you, where would I add your code? I gave you the green checkmark - I am still unsure how the code you provided should be added to mine to make it a functional program.

Comment: Thanks, @KyleOliver. I just pasted the complete code which you should be able to use directly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, now I can study it, it is much more concise than mine!