# Python: create csv file without delimiter between letters

Tags: python, csv

I want to create new `csv` file and write some string in it:

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as resultsfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(resultsfile)
    csv_writer.writerow('mystring')
```

**Output**

```
m,y,s,t,r,i,n,g
```

The thing here that the default delimiter is `comma` and there no way to use this:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(resultsfile, delimiter='')
```

So how can I write my string without any delimiter inside the `csv` file?

Comment: If you don't need a delimiter then why are you using CSV?

Comment: If you don't want a delimiter, then you don't want a csv. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: From your description it seems you just want a text file. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/python-print-string-to-text-file) how to write to a text file

Comment: Please provide an expected output.

Comment: This is task that i have

Comment: Your task doesn't make any sense. Please provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish. So far, you've merely asked to create a CSV that isn't a CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `.writerow()`. This method expects a **list** (i.e. columns), but you only give it one single string.

Give it a list of columns. If you have only one column, you *still* need to give it a list.

```
csv_writer.writerow(['mystring'])
```

Strings are also lists (of letters), which explains the behavior you see when you do this:

```
csv_writer.writerow('mystring')
```

Comment: It expects *an iterable*, not a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know, but I kept the jargon down for the OP's sake.

Comment: It's not a mere issue of jargon, for example, if it expects a list, then why did it happily take a string?

Comment: I explained that. I'm all for using the right terminology, but given the OP's level of understanding, I don't think that it's particularly helpful to throw around words like "iterable". They just want to know why the csv writer does what it does, at a conceptional level. And the conceptional level is "they passed in one item where they should have been passing a list of items" (or "a list of one item", as it were). They'll get round to understanding what an iterable is soon enough, I'm sure.