# Is there a way I can save websites text into a word file on my computer using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I made a simple automation selenium script which takes user input and based on that searches the web. Then it clicks on the first given link/website and copies/outputs all the text from the website into the command line. Now I want to save this text into a notepad or word. So I'm wondering if this is possible with selenium?

I tried searching for a method how to do this but I couldn't find anything so now I wonder if its possible to do that with selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

subjectName = str(input("Enter the name of the subject: "))

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ishak/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')


def subject_search(subject):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elem.send_keys(subject)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


subject_search(subjectName)


def given_results():
    results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//div[@class="r"]/a/h3')  # finds webresults
    results[0].click()  # clicks the first one


given_results()


myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[@id='mw-content-text']").text

print("Your text is: ", myText)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/print-string-to-text-file

Comment: Yes thanks to both of you @Vincent and Moshe Slavin! It helped me solve the problem! Cheers

Comment: Glad to help! don't forget to search before asking...