# is there a way to print someone in console aswell as in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a program where it prints a random string of digits/letters and I want it to print onto the console as well into a text file.

```
  print ( ''.join(random.choice(f"{letters2}{letters}{digits}") for i in range(0, option2)) )
  # line above prints into console
  if question == 1:
    with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
      sys.stdout = f 
      print( ## )
      sys.stdout = original_stdout 
  # I'm trying to get what it outputs to the console to print to the file aswell
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question [Writing to file in Pyhton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-to-file-in-python/)?

Comment: Use `f.write()` rather than changing stdout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print string to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/print-string-to-text-file)

Comment: well I'm trying to print what the first line outputs to console into a file

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems, you can achieve this by [piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) the output of your script to  the [`tee` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)), which displays it in the terminal and also writes it to whatever file name you provide:

```
$ python3 -c "print('hello world')" | tee out.txt
hello world
$ cat out.txt
hello world
```

Note that the first command doesn't need to be a Python script - this is a general solution for simultaneously viewing and saving the output of any program.