# Splitting a text file into two different text files

Tags: python, file, split

I have a file called `names62.txt` and it contains 62 names. There is one name per each line, so it contains 62 lines.

I need to develop a Python program that writes the 80% of the names contained in `names62.txt` to a file called `train.txt` and 20% of the names to a second output file called `test.txt`.

How can I do that? These percentages might be changed for future experiments. And I might use different names for txt output files that contains different amount of names (e.g. `names128.txt` and so on).

Comment: you have to count how many lines are X% and read lines one by one untill you reach that count. then open next file and write to it all what's left.

Comment: what you've tried already? what problems are you facing?

Comment: Does the selection need to be random or can you take the first 80% of lines for one file and the remaining 20% for the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer write the 80% of the lines of file `names62.txt` in `train.txt` and selects them sequentially from the start of `names62.txt`.

Try this code:

```
train_filename = 'train.txt'
test_filename = 'test.txt'
train = open(train_filename, 'w')
test = open(test_filename, 'w')

p1 = int(input("Insert a number for the percentage? "))
n = 0
with open('names62.txt') as f:
    for name in f:
        n += 1

num_name_in_train = (n * p1) / 100
n = 0
with open('names62.txt') as f:
    for name in f:
        n += 1
        if n <= num_name_in_train:
            train.write(name)
        else:
            test.write(name)
f.close()
train.close()
test.close()
```

### Input the filenames

I missed to customize the filenames.
To do this you can use the function:

```
train_filename = input("train filename ? ")
test_filename = input("test filename ? ")
```

### Use of context manager

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/print-string-to-text-file/5214587#5214587) recommends the use of context manager:

> It is strongly advised to use a context manager. As an advantage, it is made sure the file is always closed, no matter what:

My previous code uses a context manager only for read the file `names62.txt`, while to write to the 2 files `train.txt` and `test.txt` is used *explicit code*. [That post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/print-string-to-text-file/5214587#5214587) gives example to write to a file by context manager.