# Web scrape links with Python, then turn them into a string

Tags: python

With Python I'm having issues turning web scrapped links into strings so I can save them as either a txt or csv file. I would really like them as a txt file. This is what I have at the moment.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com/"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
type(link)

print(link, file=open('example.txt','w'))
```

I've tried all sort of things with no luck. I'm pretty much at a lose.

Comment: What doesn't work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: In Jupyter Notebook it outputs, but I cannot seem to get it to save as a text file (or csv) showing each output line.

Comment: I can only get the last "link" to print to a text file. I'm stuck trying to get all the "links" to be listed in the text document.

Comment: Show us your code regarding writing to the file, we can't see what you're doing wrong without the actual code

Comment: Everything is at the top of the page. The last line printing to the example.txt only shows the last output line found when scrapping the URL google.com. So the output is a text doc with <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
print(link, file=open('example.txt','w'))
```

Will write the `link` variable, but that's only the last one.

---

To write them all, use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com/"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

with open("example.txt", "w") as file:
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        file.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
```

Which uses a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/print-string-to-text-file) to open the file, then write each `href` with a newline.