# python ftplib storbinary in loop writes empty file

Tags: python, loops, ftplib

For a planned stress test, I am trying to write the same file to an FTP server using a loop which store files with different names obtained by a counter includes in filenames.

The program works fine only for the first file.
All the others has been created, but are empty.

Below there is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from cred import *

# Script for streestest

ftp_conn = FTP()

ftp_conn.connect(host=hostname, port=21)

ftp_conn.login(user=username, passwd=password)

counter = 0

# Testfile must exist!

try:
    file = open(file='./testfile', mode='rb')
    for i in range(10):
        filename = f'testfile{i+1}'
        ftp_conn.storbinary(cmd=f'STOR /stresstest/{filename}', fp=file)
        print(f'wrote file: {filename}')
        counter += 1

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist!')

ftp_conn.quit()

print(f'Written {counter} files to {ftp_conn.host}')
```

Thank You!

Comment: Put `file = open(...)` inside `for` cause your file was read to the end first time.

Comment: So it has to be read again and again?

Answer (score 0):

### Open and close the file for every test upload

You have to do 2 corrections to your code:

- open the file inside the for loop
- after the upload to the server FTP (`STOR` command) **close the file** `testfile`

The correct code is (I have tested it on my system):

```
from ftplib import FTP

# Script for streestest
ftp_conn = FTP()
ftp_conn.connect(host=hostname, port=21)
ftp_conn.login(user=username, passwd=password)

counter = 0

# Testfile must exist!
try:
    # move the open() inside the for loop
    #file = open(file='./testfile', mode='rb')  # <---- comment this instruction
    for i in range(10):
        file = open(file='./testfile', mode='rb')
        filename = f'testfile{i+1}'
        ftp_conn.storbinary(cmd=f'STOR /stresstest/{filename}', fp=file)
        print(f'wrote file: {filename}')
        counter += 1
        # close the file
        file.close()        # <----------- Add this close()

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist!')

ftp_conn.quit()

print(f'Written {counter} files to {ftp_conn.host}')
```

### Use a context manager

An other way is to use a context manager as in the followed code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

# Script for streestest
ftp_conn = FTP()
ftp_conn.connect(host=hostname, port=21)
ftp_conn.login(user=username, passwd=password)

counter = 0

# Testfile must exist!
try:
    for i in range(10):
        with open('./testfile', 'rb') as file:   # <---- here there is the context manager that opens the file
            filename = f'testfile{i+1}'
            ftp_conn.storbinary(cmd=f'STOR /stresstest/{filename}', fp=file)
            print(f'wrote file: {filename}')
            counter += 1

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist!')

ftp_conn.quit()

print(f'Written {counter} files to {ftp_conn.host}')
```

By a context manager the file is closed automatically.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214578/print-string-to-text-file/5214587#5214587) recommends the use of context manager, and starts with the following sentence:

> It is strongly advised to use a context manager. As an advantage, it is made sure the file is always closed, no matter what...